# How to save Ω in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to save the following string into a SQL Server 2008R2 table. The string is

```
Cable with 80Ω
```

I used the data type `varchar(max)` but in the result of select query it displays as

Cable with 80O

What to do?

Comment: Can you try `NVARCHAR(20)` ?? This is a **Unicode** column and should handle all special characters just fine - and please also use an **appropriate** length - don't just use `(max)` for everything since you're too lazy to define an appropriate length!

Comment: i used nvarchar, but in the select query it shows as Cable with 80O

Answer (score 4):

That's not a character contained in the basic ASCII range so you'll need to make your column `NVARCHAR` which allows you to store Unicode characters.

Working example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(20), col2 NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @t 
   SELECT 'Cable with 80Ω', N'Cable with 80Ω'

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Note the `N` in front of the string - this is important as it denotes national characters so SQL Server recognises that it is receiving a Unicode string